# Class for move, scale and rotate, of a uiimageview

Tags: iphone, class, uiimageview, rotation, scale

I'm creating a subclass of UIImageView that detects touches, and will move, rotate and scale the image based on the touches.  However, I really feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here, and it's driving me nuts.  Shouldn't this already exist somewhere?

Does anyone have any examples, or links to a class that is already doing this?  Or if you have a class you've written, that'd be helpful too.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out... I answered my own question.

Hopefully this is useful to someone.

For anyone who is interested, here is the implementation for a UIImageView subclass, that you can use to move, scale, and rotate an image.  It works pretty well for me.

```
    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     if( [touches count] == 1 ) {

float difx = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].x;

float dify = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].y - [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self].y;



          CGAffineTransform newTransform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, difx, dify);

          self.transform = newTransform1;

     } else     if( [touches count] == 2 ) {

int prevmidx = ([[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] previousLocationInView:self].x + [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] previousLocationInView:self].x) / 2;

int prevmidy = ([[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] previousLocationInView:self].y + [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] previousLocationInView:self].y) / 2;

int curmidx = ([[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self].x + [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self].x) / 2;

int curmidy = ([[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self].y + [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self].y) / 2;

          int difx = curmidx - prevmidx;

          int dify = curmidy - prevmidy;



CGPoint prevPoint1 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] previousLocationInView:self];

CGPoint prevPoint2 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] previousLocationInView:self];

CGPoint curPoint1 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self];

CGPoint curPoint2 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1] locationInView:self];

          float prevDistance = [self distanceBetweenPoint1:prevPoint1 andPoint2:prevPoint2];

          float newDistance = [self distanceBetweenPoint1:curPoint1 andPoint2:curPoint2];

          float sizeDifference = (newDistance / prevDistance);



          CGAffineTransform newTransform1 = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, difx, dify);

          self.transform = newTransform1;



          CGAffineTransform newTransform2 = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, sizeDifference, sizeDifference);

          self.transform = newTransform2;





          float prevAngle = [self angleBetweenPoint1:prevPoint1 andPoint2:prevPoint2];

          float curAngle = [self angleBetweenPoint1:curPoint1 andPoint2:curPoint2];

          float angleDifference = curAngle - prevAngle;



          CGAffineTransform newTransform3 = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, angleDifference);

          self.transform = newTransform3;

     }

}



- (NSInteger)distanceBetweenPoint1:(CGPoint)point1 andPoint2:(CGPoint)point2 {

     CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(point1.x - point2.x);

     CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(point1.y - point2.y);

     CGFloat distance = sqrt((deltaY*deltaY)+(deltaX*deltaX));

     return distance;

}



- (CGFloat)angleBetweenPoint1:(CGPoint)point1 andPoint2:(CGPoint)point2

{ 

     CGFloat deltaY = point1.y - point2.y;

     CGFloat deltaX = point1.x - point2.x;

     CGFloat angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

     return angle;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at Erica Sadun's example from the iphone dev cookbook (oreilly). It's in chapter 8 on gestures and touches.

http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate/